# Volume of domain bounded by $f(x, y) = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume, multiple-integral

The full question is as follow:

> Given the function
> $$
> f(x, y) = \log(x^2 + y^2) 
> $$
> for $x^2 + y^2 > 0$, using cylindrical coordinates $r, \theta$ and $z$, find the volume of the (closed) domain, $D$, which is bounded by: the graph of the function $f(x, y)$, the xy plane, and the plane given by $z = 10$. Moreover, $(0, 0, 0) \in D$.

**My attempt**

First intuition tells me that the domain is an "expanding circle" of sorts as $z$ changes.

Since $D$ is bounded by the xy plane and the plane given by $z = 10$, the range of $z$ is $0 \lt z \le 10$.

Finding the bounds of $r$, given $0 \lt z \le 10$,

\begin{align*}
\log(x^2 + y^2) &= 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\log(x^2 + y^2) &= 10 \\
x^2 + y^2 &= e^{10}
\end{align*}

which are circles with radius $1$ and $e^5$ respectively.

Hence, the volume of D is

\begin{align*}
D &= \iiint_V dz \ dy \ dx \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{e^5}r \int_{\log r^2}^{10} dz \ dr \ d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{e^5} 10r - r \log r^2 \ dr \ d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\left(5r^2 - \frac 1 4 (\log r^2)^2\right)\Big|_1^{e^5} d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} 5e^{10} - 30 \ d\theta \\
&= 2\pi(5e^{10} - 30)
\end{align*}

I am not sure if the final answer is correct and whether my reasoning for the integration bounds is right as well. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You assume that the domain D is cylindrical and bounded by $f(x,y) = z$, but that is not clear from the question. It seems to me you could just as well have assumed $f(x,y) = C$, where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: @M.Wind $f(x,y) = C$ is a curve and not a surface. In the context of the given question, OP's interpretation is correct though the question should have explicitly mentioned it.

Comment: Well, in my opinion the phrase: "the volume of the  domain $D$ which is bounded by the graph of the function $f(x,y)$" is meaningless. The function $f(x,y)$ in itself does not define a boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes -

i) you are leaving the volume of the cylinder in the middle with $0 \leq r \leq 1$. It has volume of $10 \pi$.

ii) The integral of $~ r \ln r^2$ is not correct.

I would rather use the disc method so it is just one integral and the integral is more straightforward too.

$z = \ln(x^2+y^2) = \ln r^2 \implies r = e^{(z/2)}$

So, $ V = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{10} \int_0^{e^{(z/2)}} r ~dr ~ dz ~ d\theta = (e^{10} - 1) \pi$

---

Edit: Adding diagrams which should help you visualize your mistake that I mentioned in point $(i)$.

Here is a $3D$ diagram and as the lower bound of $r$ you have is $1$, your integral set up is not integrating over $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and is hence leaving out the volume in the middle. See the base of the left out cylinder volume, marked in black.

[image]

Now let me re-iterate the same by showing 2D projection in xz plane. The integral setup of yours only considers the region shaded in turquoise color but misses the region in the middle that is shaded in grey.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but since $D$ is bounded by the $x-y$ plane ($z = 0)$, how is it possible to get $0 \le r \le 1$? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @iobtl think this way - you have a unit circle in xy-plane and the size of the circle keeps increasing. The way you are integrating, you are only considering the volume between the surface and plane $z = 10$ but you are leaving the part that sits above the unit circle in the xy-plane.

Comment: The way you are integrating, it should be the integral you have PLUS $ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{10} r ~ dz ~ dr ~ d\theta$

Comment: Take another example. Say you have a cone $z = r-1$ and you are finding its volume between x-y plane ($z = 0$) and $z = 10$, what will the volume be? Note the vertex of the cone is at $z = -1$ and at $z = 0, r = 1$ so you are finding volume of conical frustum.

Comment: I see, the diagram helps a lot, but I'll have to ponder over this a bit more. Thanks for the response, btw.